# C++ byte order when casting int to byte array

Tags: c++, casting, endianness

Given that my platform is little endian, I assumed that a four-byte integer value of 1 would be represented as `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x01` when expressed as a byte array. With that, could someone explain to me why the following assertion fails ...

```
int val{1};
auto bytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val);
assert(bytes[sizeof(int) - 1] == 0x01);
```

... but the following assertion succeeds ...

```
assert(bytes[0] == 0x01);
```

After the cast to `char*`, the bytes appear to be reversed. Are my assumptions about endianness wrong? Is the compiler (clang) or language abstracting away the endianness? What's going on?

Comment: Little endian - first byte is the smallest - ie. 1

Comment: Little endian means "little end first", "little end" = "least significant", "first" in memory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your assumption is reversed.  In little endian, a 32bit integer value of 1 is represented in hex as `0x00000001`, but is represented in bytes as `0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00`.

Answer (score 5):

Little endian means you write or store the least-significant digit of the number first.  Big endian means you write or store the most-significant digit first.

Consider the way we normally write numbers on paper.  When writing the base 10 number 4823 on paper, we write it big-endian.  The first digit, 4, is the thousands digit.  We call it the most significant digit because it has the greatest effect on the number's magnitude.  The second digit, 8, is the hundreds digit.  The third digit, 2, is the tens digit.  The fourth (and last) digit, 3, is the ones (or units) digit.  We call the ones digit the least significant because it has the smallest effect on the number's magnitude.

A four-byte (32-bit) integer is stored in memory as a base 256 number.  Each byte is one digit, but the digits range from 0 to 255 instead of just from 0 to 9.

A little endian platform stores the least significant byte, the ones digit, first.  The 256s digit is the second byte.  The 65536s digit is the third byte.  The 16777216s digit is fourth (and last).

Thus in your example, we could write the number on paper as 0x00000001 (because we almost always write numbers on paper big-endian), but on a little endian system, the bytes (base 256 digits) are stored in the order `01 00 00 00`.

(Note that we cannot address individual bits directly on most systems.  Thus there's no way to tell, at the machine code level, whether the individual bits in a byte are stored little-endian or big-endian, or whether that is even a meaningful concept at the hardware level.  That's why I say the number is stored in base 256, not base 2.)

Answer (score 4):

You said,

> Given that my platform is little endian, I assumed that a four-byte integer value of 1 would be represented as `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x01` when expressed as a byte array.

Incorrect assumption. That would be the big endian system. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Little endian means least significant digit first, so in memory you'll have `0x00000001` for `1`. Notice that "first" here means on the right, because that's where truncation happens. If you cast that 32 bit integer to an 8 bit integer, you'll get the right-most part (ie `0x01`).

Comment: A byte-by-byte picture from base-address on would probably be clearer. In memory you'll have `01 00 00 00` for little endian, `00 00 00 01` for big-endian. And I don't see what "truncation" has to do with the OP's code whatsoever, and is incorrect anyway. A cast from 32-bit `int` to 8-bit int. will be done by value representation; not memory-layout. It doesn't matter whether you're on a big endian or little endian machine, `static_cast<char>(int(1))` will result in a `char` with value `0x01`.